# How to print occurrences to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here I am trying to print the first and second wt^ with its corresponding s^ to output file and remaining wt^ and p^ should be printed to another output file.
how can I do this?

input file will be like this

```
 wt^RHEL System Overview(contd..) 
            s^Supported architectures include:
            s^32-bit x86 compatible systems
            s^64-bit AMD64 (Opteron) and Intel EM64T systems


    wt^RHEL System Overview(contd..)        
                s^Common deployments        
                s^High volume deployments include:
                s^Corporate applications (CRM, ERP, etc.)
                s^Databases

    wt^RHEL System Overview(contd..)
            s^Network infrastructure systems
            s^Web serving
            s^File/print serving
            s^HPC compute systems
```

output file should be like this

output1.txt:

```
wt^RHEL System Overview(contd..) 
                s^Supported architectures include:
                s^32-bit x86 compatible systems
                s^64-bit AMD64 (Opteron) and Intel EM64T systems


        wt^RHEL System Overview(contd..)        
                    s^Common deployments        
                    s^High volume deployments include:
                    s^Corporate applications (CRM, ERP, etc.)
                    s^Databases
```

output2.txt:

```
wt^RHEL System Overview(contd..)
                s^Network infrastructure systems
                s^Web serving
                s^File/print serving
                s^HPC compute systems
```

I have tried

```
count=$(cat $( ls unit-*-slides.txt | sort -n ) | grep -E "[ ]*(st\^|p\^)" >> output.txt)
```

but this is printing whole stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over the years i have came to believe `awk` can do almost  anything, (is the `^` necessary?)

`awk 'BEGIN {fout="file1";} /wt/{i++}i==3{fout="file2";} {print $0 > fout}' <filename>`